# Find number of days between two dates in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to find number of days between two dates based on a slicer.

I have a table visual which shows the data based on given date slicer.

I have a date column called "Sampled_date", "Template" which has 260000 rows. I am using a slicer which has "Sampled_date" and passing the dates 6/1/2023 to 9/8/2023. I need to find the number of days between given dates in a slicer. I have the Template ID's which are having data only for some dates. But i need to get 99 in each and every case in the table regardless of the data present for the dates. For suppose if i apply the slicer and see the result i am getting 6 as data for one "Template" is having only from 6/1/2023 to 6/6/2023 but i need to see 99 even in that case also.

I tried this formula but it didn't work.

```
Days = 

var startdate = MIN([sampled_date])

var enddate = MAX([sampled_date])

return DATEDIFF(startdate,enddate,DAY)
```

This formula is taking only min and max for the template data based on dates and showing result but i need to get from 6/1/2023 to 9/8/2023 as 99 for every record.

Comment: Number of days selected in the slicer? Is your `Days` calculation a measure or calculated column?

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the visual interaction through the slicer and then with same measure you will get 99 for each row record.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. I didn't get the point.

Comment: Please send me pbix file so i will do this quickly for you

Comment: I can't send the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ALLSELECTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax):

```
slicer_range = 
var startdate = MINX(ALLSELECTED('My_table'), 'My_table'[sampled_date])
var enddate = MAXX(ALLSELECTED('My_Table'), 'My_table'[sampled_date])
return
    DATEDIFF(startdate, enddate, DAY)
```

However, I'm getting only 95 days!

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. For ex: If one ID is having data from 6/1/2023 to 6/30/2023 it shows only 30 days but i need to show 99 even when there is no data after 6/30/2023 in the given date range 6/1/2023 to 9/8/2023.